# ¿Cómo sumar o restar un valor a un mismo dato varias veces en Java?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Tengo este código:

```
  do{

        System.out.println("Seleccionar alimento o actividad:\n ");




        System.out.println("**** Alimentos y actividades que matan. ****\n");
        System.out.println("1. Carne."+"("+alimento[0].getPuntos()+") pts.") ;
        System.out.println("2. Pan." +"("+alimento[1].getPuntos()+") pts.");
        System.out.println("3. Saltar."+"("+alimento[2].getPuntos() +") pts.");

        System.out.println("**** Alimentos y actividades que dan vida. **** ");
        System.out.println("4. Verduras." +"("+alimento[4].getPuntos() +") pts.") ;
        System.out.println("5. Cereal."+"("+alimento[5].getPuntos() +") pts.");
        System.out.println("6. Dormir."+"("+alimento[6].getPuntos() +") pts.");
        System.out.println("7. Salir.\n");

        System.out.println("Seleccione acción: ");
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nUsted eligió: " +alimento[opcion - 1].getNombre());
        System.out.println("Antes su vida era de: " +personaje[eleccion - 1].getVida());
        System.out.println("Su estado actual es: " +personaje[eleccion - 1].isEstado());


        vida = personaje[eleccion - 1].getVida() + alimento[opcion - 1].getPuntos();
        System.out.println("La vida del personaje ahora es: " +personaje[eleccion - 1].getNombre()+" es: " +vida);

        System.out.println("Desea alimenat de nuevo: S/s o N/n");
        tecla = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); 





    }while(tecla.equals("S") || tecla.equals("s"));
     return eleccion;
```

Pretendo que al terminar de elegir el alimento para el personaje y realizar la resta o suma según corresponda para determinar la vida del personaje ésta vuelva a ejecutarse pero con la última vida que obtuve.

Ejemplo:
Si tengo 20 de vida y como Carne(-5 pts).
Ahora la vida es de 15.

Deseo volver a seleccionar alimento o actividad.
Tengo 15 de vida ahora y como Cereal(10 pts):
Ahora la vida es de 25.

El objetivo es alimentar tantas veces pueda al personaje con las cosas que quiera. Si llega a 0 el personaje muere.

Intenté colocar un do-while anidado en cada caso pero no es nada práctico, aunque si funciona como quiero de esa forma.

Comment: No entiendo bien.  ¿Por qué no usas un setter y simplemente actualizas la vida del personaje ? intenta vida = personaje[eleccion - 1].getVida(); personaje[eleccion - 1].setVida(vida - alimento[eleccion - 1].getPuntos());

Answer (score 2):

En la línea:

```
vida = personaje[eleccion - 1].getVida() + alimento[opcion - 1].getPuntos();
```

la cual puedes cambiar por:

```
personaje[eleccion - 1].setVida(personaje[eleccion - 1].getVida() - alimento[opcion - 1].getPuntos());
```

Comment: gracias por el comentario, tu solución me corrió pero me da valores que existen en mi programa pero no son los que le estoy pidiendo. Si observas bien cada alimento tienen Pts, bueno tu línea es eso lo que me manda y lo que yo busco es el sumarle o restarle a la vida esos puntos y que lo imprima.

Comment: @angel_elias Puedes agregar un atributo a la clase "Alimento" en el cual  indicar si el valor del atributo "puntos" debe sumarse o restarse, y antes de hacer **personaje.setVida(...)** creas un **if** consultando el valor de ese nuevo atributo.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien tu problema. Supongamos que tienes una clase `Persona` y otra `Alimento`:

```java
public class Persona {

    private int vida;

    // constructor, getters y setters
}
```

```java
public class Alimento {

    private int puntos;

    // constructor, getters y setters
}
```

En tu bucle, sólo actualizas la vida del personaje:

```java
do {
    // preguntar por la actividad y alimento
    Personaje personaje = personajes[seleccion - 1];
    Alimento alimento = alimentos[opcion - 1];

    personaje.setVida(personaje.getVida() - alimento.getPuntos());

    // preguntar si quiere seguir jugando 
} while (condicion);
```

Y eso sería todo. No necesitas bucles anidados, sólo actualizar el estado del objeto.

Comment: @Paul Vargas La palabra "solo" no lleva tilde según la RAE. Más información en: http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde.